How can I apply greyscale colouring to a Google Map?
The now deprecated legacy version of cloud-based Maps Styles has a saturation control:

This makes it trivial to create a greyscale effect of land, sea, rivers, etc. without it affecting things such as InfoWindow popups.
The new version of cloud-based Map Styles which Google has mandated we upgrade to does not have the same control.
It's not currently possible to style all of the map features individually due to an existing issue with the new version of the Maps Styles interface. It would also be tedious to do so.
The new JSON API for applying styles outside of the cloud-maps platform doesn't appear to have been released or documented yet, so I couldn't apply this manually even if I wanted to.
I can't apply a CSS filter on the container div to the Google Map, because that will also apply the effect to map markers and InfoWindow popups.
How can I apply greyscale colouring to a Google Map as per the example screenshot from the legacy Map Styles?

I really can't see why/how the issue you mentioned would be related to a missing feature from the new style editor. If you need that feature, open a feature request.

Because Google has deprecated the legacy map styles editor where this was possible and is mandating that we upgrade to the new map styles editor where this feature is missing. The styling is supposed to carry over from the legacy version when upgrading, but it doesn't. The "upgrade" is a breaking change. I'm asking how I can achieve the same effect now.
